# Avoiding Repetition from one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table

```
sid id  rNum    str      power  con1  rc
15  287 6       Grit     0      0    225
15  288 7       Short    0      0    225
15  289 8       Grade    0      0    225
16  224 3       Mega     0      1    222
17  432 7       Server   0      0    656
```

I wish to have result as

```
sid id  rNum    str      power  con1  rc
15  287 6       Grit     0      0    225
16  224 3       Mega     0      1    222
17  432 7       Server   0      0    656
```

Which means I want to show unique "sid" with the very first value from the group

I have tried the distinct but not getting desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with a subquery. Assuming the the *first* record per `sid` is the record with the smallest `id`, that would be:

```
select t.*
from myable t
where t.id= (select min(r1.id) from mytable t1 where t1.sid = t.sid)
```

Alternatively, you can also use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by sid order by id) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

With row_number() window function:

```
select t.sid, t.id, t.rNum, t.str, t.power, t.con1, t.rc
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by sid order by id) rn
  from tablename
) t
where t.rn = 1
```